# Fill spreadsheet table with list of names

Tags: excel, list, spreadsheet, fill

I need to fill an empty table (from an excel spreadsheet) with a list of values from a list of 13 values (names I have written in a different sheet) always in the same order. For example

Spreadsheet

[image: See example of the spreadsheet]

Is there any way to do it without using a Macro? If there is no other way, then a Macro would be OK. I tried many things for weeks and I cannot figure it out :( 
Thank you very much!

Comment: Can you copy/paste? Or a Vlookup maybe? What have you tried so far?

Comment: yes, I can copy paste but only 5 names at a time (and the idea es that the list changes and varies from month o month), that's why I'm looking for an automated way to do it, if possible.

Comment: So the names (might) change but the order always stays the same? name1-13 across night day and weekend

Comment: Let's say that the names are always 13 and in the same order. If it changes, that could be in a different spreadsheet and in the future (maybe up to 50 names, but so far they are 13).

Comment: If it's currently 13 then you have a pattern, that is only 13 rows deep, so you can just use find&replace on the name that changes in the pattern, then just copy in the next row. When it gets to 50 names that will be different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this formula in the range `C2:G9`:

```
=Index( Sheet2!$A:$A ,Mod(Row()*5+Column()-13,CountA( Sheet2!$A:$A ))+1)
```

just replace `Sheet2!$A:$A` with the column or range where the names are.

( `-13` is short for `-ROW(C2)*5+COLUMN(C2)` where `C2` is the first cell where the names will be )

Comment: Thanks Slai! it worked  :) I appreciate your taking your time to help me...it was driving me crazy!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so it's a bit convoluted but I'll pull it into parts for now:

Add a new sheet:

in Column A put the list of names, make sure that cell A1 has heading of **NAMES**

in B2 put:

```
=Counta(A:A)
```

In cell C2 put `2`

In Cell D2 put `=IF(C2+1>$B$2,1,C2+1)`  - fill this across to G2

In Cell C3 put `=IF(G2+1>$B$2,1,G2+1)`

Then Fill this down as far as needed.

Then in Cell I2 put `=HLOOKUP($A$1,$A:$A,C2,FALSE)` 
*You can see here why we need the "header" row in A1*

Fill this down as far as needed.

Example of how it looks with outputs:
[image: Image showing what above text outputs would be]

Example where you can see the formula:
[image: Image showing what above formula look like]

Now you can replace names, Add new names to the List of names etc, and it will keep the order and pattern.

I thought about putting all the formula into one cell, but for clarity have left them separate.

Comment: Thanks Delta_zulu....I tried to use your solution but it didn't work because after G2 comes H...and it wouldn't work. :(
Anyway, I used Slai answer. but thanks anyway!